# listview as action overflow in sherlock actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

How to do get a listdropdown on clicking sherlock action item.It should be similar to creating spinner. But I have a problem with that approach as I dont want the selected item to be shown on the actionbar.it should be similatr to action overflow.Can any on help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create such behavior using `Spinner` (or `IcsSpinner` for `ActionBarSherlock`) in action layout of a menu item. Though you have to use a little trick - hide the currently selected item.

Create menu xml:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/item1"
          android:actionLayout="@layout/my_dropdown_action_layout"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Where `res/layout-v14/my_dropdown_action_layout.xml` will contain (this version is used for native action bar):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
             android:id="@+id/spinner"/>
```

and `res/layout/my_dropdown_action_layout.xml` will contain (this version is used for `ActionBarSherlock`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner 
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
             android:id="@+id/spinner"/>
```

Using `IcsSpinner` is necessary to create a dropdown spinner. If you use `res/layout-v14/my_dropdown_action_layout.xml` layout for the default version (in `res/layout/`), it would behave differently on Android 2.x (the spinner would be in dialog mode).

Now you have to fill the spinner with data properly. Just create an `Activity` where you inflate the menu, this way:

```java
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.text, items);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.list_item);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        // native ActionBar
        Spinner sp = (Spinner) menuItem.getActionView();
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        // ActionBarSherlock
        IcsSpinner sp = (IcsSpinner) menuItem.getActionView();
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Now comes the trick of hiding the currently selected item. Layout `res/layout/spinner_layout.xml` will contain this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:background="@null">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/my_dropdown_icon"
            android:background="@null"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This way you see an icon as the menu item and you have the dropdown menu. Note that layout `res/layout/list_item.xml` has to contain a `TextView` with id `R.id.text` too.

Alternatively, you can use similar approach where you can use [`ActionProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionProvider.html) instead of action layout.

And another solution would be to create custom widget similar to dropdown `Spinner`.